# How to overly sider of antd layout over antd content

Tags: antd

I want to overly antd sider over antd content

I tried to apply zIndex but it's not correct approach

Please suggest me any correct approach

https://ant.design/components/layout/#Layout.Sider

Answer (score 0):

If you want your sider to appear on top of content when visible then you should use antd Drawer instead.